How can I manually compare two numpy arrays element by element?
I'm trying to implement (in python) a soft comparison between two 2-dimensional images, each with an r,g,b value. They're guaranteed to be the same size. I just want to subtract one from the other and check if any of the elements of that subtraction are above a given tolerance. I think I'm doing this right. Is this the correct way to index and compare two numpy arrays?
for y in range(0, self.image1.shape[1]):
    for x in range(0, self.image2.shape[0]):
        if max(self.image1[x,y] - self.image2[x,y]) > tolerance:

I'm trying to compare the results of a subtraction to a tolerance value, using the max() method on the result to pull out the largest difference. The data that I'm working with has three elements to each pixel, r, g, and b. I think this is the right way to do this?

Why not just use image1 - image2 and check if any of the values are outside the tolerance?

Don't use for loops.  numpy arrays are designed for element-by-element, vectorized operations.  I would do something like this:
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(48.).reshape(6, 8)
>>> b = a.copy()  # no difference from a
>>> c = a.copy()
>>> c[0, 0] += 0.0001  # differs from a in one cell
>>> tol = 1e-6
>>> # "mask" array of True and False
>>> diff_ab = np.abs(a - b) > tol
>>> diff_ab
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]])
>>> diff_ab.sum()  # total number of differences
0
>>> diff_ac = np.abs(a - c) > tol
>>> diff_ac
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]])
>>> diff_ac.sum()  # total number of differences
1
>>> np.where(diff_ac)  # tuple of indices where the difference is greater than the tolerance
(array([0], dtype=int64), array([0], dtype=int64))

This approach will work for arrays of any dimensionality.

There is an API for this: allclose
np.allclose(image1, image2, rtol=0, atol=tolerance)

So you do not need to do this "manually".
However, if you really want to do this "manually", you need to be careful about overflow.
That is, if your image is uint8, then np.uint8(1) - np.uint8(2) = np.uint8(254).
import numpy as np


def baseline(image1, image2, tolerance):
    for y in range(0, image1.shape[1]):
        for x in range(0, image2.shape[0]):
            if max(image1[x, y] - image2[x, y]) > tolerance:
                return False
    return True


def manual_allclose(image1, image2, tolerance):
    return np.all(np.abs(image1 - image2) <= tolerance)


def np_allclose(image1, image2, tolerance):
    return np.allclose(image1, image2, rtol=0, atol=tolerance)


def main():
    image1 = np.array([[[1, 5, 1]]], dtype=np.uint8)
    image2 = np.array([[[1, 1, 5]]], dtype=np.uint8)
    assert image1.shape == image2.shape
    assert image1.dtype == image2.dtype

    for f in [baseline, manual_allclose, np_allclose]:
        for i in (3, 4):
            r = f(image1, image2, i)
            print(f"{f.__name__}, tol={i}: {r}")


main()

baseline, tol=3: False
baseline, tol=4: False
manual_allclose, tol=3: False
manual_allclose, tol=4: False
np_allclose, tol=3: False
np_allclose, tol=4: True

As you can see, only np.allclose returns the correct answer.
This is because np.allclose casts the input to float64.
So if you are going to do it manually, this is the correct implementation (if the image is uint8).
def manual_allclose_for_uint8(image1, image2, tolerance):
    assert image1.dtype == image2.dtype == np.uint8
    return np.all(np.abs(image1.astype(np.int16) - image2) <= tolerance)

